# Is it sloppy to use Exit Function keyword?

Tags: vb.net

In my subs, I usually perform several forms of validation before proceeding with the sub. Is it a bad habit to exit the sub? For example:

```
Private Sub mySub()

    if Not Validated() then
        exit sub
    end if

   'do stuff
End sub
```

Would it be better to enclose the entire body in an If-Then statement?

```
private sub mySub()
    if validated then
       'do stuff
     end if
end sub
```

Comment: What about [`Return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/return-statement)?

Comment: No. in fact it is easier to read. (Or use Return as Tadman says)